# Помогите с первичным ключом в SQL Server (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

У меня есть таблицы **Назначения** и **Штат** и мне нужно сделать внешний ключ в диаграмме, но у меня ошибка

- 'Назначения' table saved successfully
  'Штат' table
- Unable to create relationship 'FK_Штат_Назначения'.
  The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Штат_Назначения". The conflict occurred in database "pr1-2", table "dbo.Назначения", column 'номер_записи'.

*Назначения*

```
USE [pr1-2]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Назначения]    Script Date: 2/4/2024 3:40:49 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Назначения](
    [номер_записи] [int] NOT NULL,
    [кодОтдела] [int] NOT NULL,
    [кодДолжности] [int] NOT NULL,
    [номер] [int] NOT NULL,
    [датаПриема] [date] NOT NULL,
    [датаУвольнения] [date] NULL,
    [статус] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Назначения] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [номер_записи] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Назначения]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Назначения_Сотрудники] FOREIGN KEY([номер])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Сотрудники] ([номер])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Назначения] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Назначения_Сотрудники]
GO
```

*Штат*

```
USE [pr1-2]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Штат]    Script Date: 2/4/2024 3:41:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Штат](
    [кодОтдела] [int] NOT NULL,
    [кодДолжности] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Кол_во] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Штат] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [кодОтдела] ASC,
    [кодДолжности] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Штат]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Штат_Должности] FOREIGN KEY([кодДолжности])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Должности] ([кодДолжности])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Штат] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Штат_Должности]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Штат]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Штат_Отделы] FOREIGN KEY([кодОтдела])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Отделы] ([кодОтдела])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Штат] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Штат_Отделы]
GO
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В SSMS для обоих таблиц сделайте "Script Table as --> CREATE to" и вставьте код в вопрос. Также добавьте код, которым вы создаёте новый ключ. Картинки можете удалить.

Comment: @rotabor я забыл написать что эта ошибка у меня появилась при создание диаграммы

Comment: И что с чем вы пытались соединить на диаграмме?

Comment: кодДолжности из Таблицы Штат к кодДолжности в таблице Назначения

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тексту ошибки, вы сделали не то, что хотели (кодДолжности из Таблицы Штат к кодДолжности в таблице Назначения).

Обратите внимание на шаги:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там нужно выбрать [кодДолжности]:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Учтите, что у вас ключ "PK_Штат = [кодОтдела] & [кодДолжности]". И связь между таблицами длжна быть соответствующей.

**P. S.** Ещё раз. В Штате уникальность записей по комбинации [кодОтдела] & [кодДолжности]. Поэтому нельзя связать Назначения и Штат только по [кодОтдела] или по [кодДолжности]. Нужно по обоим полям. Но тогда каждое из этих полей в Штате должно быть с уникальными значениями, что противоречит начальным данным ([кодОтдела] - уникальное, а [кодДолжности] - нет).

Поэтому, нужно добавить в Штат уникальное поле [код штата], а в Назначениях заменить [кодОтдела] и [кодДолжности] на [код штата], и связывать две таблицы по [код штата].

Comment: то есть я должен сделать PK (кодОтдела) и (кодДолжности) ?? Но я так сделал и у меня ошибка (ПРИКРЕПИЛ КАРТИНКУ)

Comment: Так зачам же вы пытетесь связать  [кодОтдела] и [кодДолжности]? Нужно  [кодОтдела] с  [кодОтдела], [кодДолжности] с [кодДолжности]. И ещё поля, на которые ссылается FK, должны быть с уникальными значениями. У вас PK_Штат = [кодОтдела] & [кодДолжности] д. б. уникальным. Как сделать ключ по парам полей, пока не знаю. Нужно подумать.

Comment: Сходу приходит на ум только добавить в Штат уникальное поле [код штата], а в Назначениях заменить [кодОтдела] и [кодДолжности] на [код штата], и связывать две таблицы по [код штата].

Comment: у меня кодОтдела связан с кодОтделом в другой таблице отделы, я прикрепил картинку диаграммы

Comment: "у меня кодОтдела связан с кодОтделом" - это не мешает устанавливать другие ограничения (ключи). Но вам нужно сделать через [код штата], как я написал выше.

Comment: а почему во второй диаграмме все в порядке? Там ошибок нет.  Это диаграмма другого человека.

Comment: То, что диаграмма нарисована, не говорит о том, что нет ошибок в связях между таблицами.

Comment: См. post scriptum в ответе.

Comment: а почнму я просто не могу соединить кодДолжности из штатов к кодДолжности в Назначения? Почему это не работает ? Там же одинаковые значения. И про ваш ответ если я сделаю Код_штата, то мне нужно удалять кодДолжности из таблицы Штат?

Comment: Можно, будет работать. А какой в этом смысл? Связи должны отражать содержание информации. Ещё раз перечитайте post scriptum в ответе. Что эта связь будет определять в структуре данных? Назначение происходит не на какую-то должность, а на конкретное рабочее место - должность в отделе.

Comment: "мне нужно удалять кодДолжности из таблицы Штат?" разве я такое писал??? Нужно в Назначениях удалить [кодОтдела] и [кодДолжности], а добавить [код штата].

Comment: Таблица Отделы лишняя. Очевидно, что в Штате [кодОтдела] уникальный, поэтому [названниеОтдела] можно включить в Штат.